# Multiple Results Sets in EF 5

Tags: entity-framework-5

So I am following the instructions found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj691402 concerning how to handle multiple result sets from in EF.

I am trying to avoid the second solution as this will involve changing the EDMX by hand, which concerns me as I do not want to have to worry about other members on my team overwriting them.

But the first example still seems to be lacking. It refers to the `ObjectContext.Translate<TEntity>` method, but no where does it say how the `<TEntity>` is being created. Any time I create an Entity by hand, I of course get Error 2062, "no mapping between entity set and association set". Is there a step that I am missing? Or does the first solution not work with a DB first approach?

Comment: <TEntity> is not created.  It's a type definitions.  It's like List<T>.  You don't actually create something called T.  Translate<> creates the objects itself from the DbDataReader

Comment: I apologize as I was not clear enough before. I was asking, in regards to the example, where are these types created? There is no mention of how the "Blog" and "Post" entities and the "Blogs" and "Posts" entity sets are being created.

Answer (score 1):

If you have create entity by hand in EF designer without mapping it to existing table or database view you indeed receive an error. Try to create complex type instead.

Comment: If I create a complex type, the first example will not work as the Translate method requires the name of the Entity Set. Correct me if I am wrong, but I cannot create an Entity Set using Complex Types.